# Spring support for MongoDB 3.4 Decimal128

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Im using `spring data mongodb 1.10.1` and `spring boot 1.5.2`. I have converted older BigDecimal fields (which represents as string in db) to Decimal128 which introduced in MongoDB 3.4.

Example domain class field:

```
private Decimal128 payments = Decimal128.POSITIVE_ZERO;

 public BigDecimal getPayments() {
    return payments.bigDecimalValue();
}

public void setPayments(BigDecimal payments) {
    this.payments = new Decimal128(payments);
}
```

After initially having couple of issues, now I'm facing the issue given below.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for org.bson.types.Decimal128
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:234)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1214)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:84)
```

According to the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-conversion) it supports Decimal128. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a minimally reproducible test case? Works for me if I generate a Spring Boot 1.5.2 project using Spring Data MongoDB 1.10.1 and MongoDB driver 3.4.2.